# Сменить директорию в git bash

Tags: git

Я хочу в git bash написать команду cd. Я на рабочем столе создал папку 4. В ней есть папка work. Внутри папки work файл 1.html. Я пишу в git bash $ cd 4 / work. Он выдает bash: cd: too many arguments. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вводить эту команду в git bash.

Comment: Наверное, как обычно в большинстве командных оболочек: `cd 4/work`

Comment: `cd ~/desctop/4/work` попробуйте так

Comment: с английского переводиться как слишком много аргументов. чтобы путь задать как один аргумент можно заключить в кавычки, но вы должны понять, что система пробелы воспримет как имя директории с пробелом и имя файла так-же с пробелом. решением будет просто убрать эти пробелы и для надёжности закрепить в кавычках. `cd "4/work"`

Answer (score 0):

Операционная система то какая?

Смотрите.

Первое, что Вас должно *насторожить*, когда возникает такая проблема - это то, что Вы создаёте папку на рабочем столе.

Давайте попробуем разобраться.

Я буду исходить из того, что у Вас установлен линукс.

Когда у Вас открывается баш, то слева, до курсора, написан путь в файловой системе. Это - то место, где Вы находитесь сейчас. Что то вроде `/home/kirill/` Если Вы сомневаетесь, то есть команда `pwd`, которая выводит этот путь.

Когда Вы создаёте папку на рабочем столе - то это не то же самое, что создать папку в текущей директории баша.

Попробуйте её найти, навскидку - это будет что то вроде `/home/kirill/Desktop/`

когда найдёте и перейдёте в ту директорию, где есть папка `4` - тогда самое время писать `cd 4/work/`, и *не забудьте*, что между `4`, слешем и `work` не должно быть пробелов.

Скорее всего, именно они и вызвали сообщение "too many arguments"

Comment: `git bash` это приложение под windows.